# Why won't python webassets pyscss regenerate css from scss files in debug mode?

Tags: python, css, debugging, sass, webassets

I'm using the pyscss compiler in the python webassets library with webassets debug configs all set to true. But when I make changes to an scss file and reload the page that includes the generated css file, I see that the css file has not be regenerated and does not include my changes.  Why is this happening?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `depends='*.scss'` as noted in this [issue on GitHub](https://github.com/miracle2k/webassets/issues/231).

Comment: Using `depends` is the solution.  More on how to use it [here](https://github.com/miracle2k/webassets/blob/master/docs/bundles.rst)

Answer (score 5):

Figured it out. Webassets does not pick up on changes to scss files that are included in other scss files using `@import`. The only solution is to always make a change to the including scss file if you make a change to the included one.